# DocumentationFile created by a referenced library does not get copied to the project's bin

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I have an API project that has a few libraries as references. Each of those libraries creates a documentation XML file by including

```
<DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml</DocumentationFile>
```

in the project.

When I build my API project, it pulls all the XML files from each of the referenced libraries, except one.

Here's the main property group of one that does copy over:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml
  </DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And here's the one for the project that doesn't copy over:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml
  </DocumentationFile>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've tried removing GenerateDocumentationFile, but that makes no difference.

The XML does get generated, but remains in the library's bin. It never gets copied to the API project's bin directory.

Both of these libraries are referenced via project references.

It is possible that the library whose XML is not being copied over is being referenced inside a nuget that the API references. Could that be the cause?

I need the XML files for including example values in the Swagger.

Comment: I normally use menu Project : Add Existing Item.  Then item will appear in the Solution Explorer.   Then right click object in solution explorer and select Properties.  Then change Copy property from "Do Not Copy" to "Copy if Newer".

Comment: I did some tests and it seems that the xml files from the nuget packages cannot be copied into the project folder when building. This link(https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9498) maybe can help you on this issue.